# In firebase, what security rules should I write to allow only push to object

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-security

I have messages object in root, which simply array of strings.
I want to allow users push new objects. If they can push to messages root, they should have write permission to it, that's mean they can easily replace whole messages object with other valid data. What kind of security rules should I write to avoid this?

Comment: what you're looking for is a "write only if there is not data in the location yet" rule. There is an example of that in the Firebase documentation. I'll look it up once I'm on a better keyboard.

Comment: Found the link, but Saeed already answered in the meantime. Just for completeness, the security guide provides exactly the example you're looking for in this section: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-data-variables

Answer (score 7):

You can write a rule to allow adding data if data does not exist, but prevent data from being modified or deleted using the following rule.

```
".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()"
```

The 'data' variable is the current data in Firebase.  'newData' is the resulting data if the write is allowed.

For more detailed explanation, please check out [Security & Rules API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/).

Comment: Hi Saeed, this is also what i though, but I can't make it work. I'm pushing to a location feedback using the write rule: `"feedback": {
          ".write": "!data.exists()"
        }` . If feedback does not exist, the first push succeeds, but the next one gets the following error: `FIREBASE WARNING: set at /feedback/-KDQSPPW7e9QurROMUb7 failed: permission_denied`. Apparently data.exist() is true once something is under the location `feedback`. Do you have any idea what I'm making wrong?

Comment: found an answer. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

The full rules definition should read

```
{
   "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        "feedback": {
            "$key": {
               ".write": "!data.exists()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This lets you push at the `/feedback` location. You can freely choose the variable name `$key`